# Как получить доступ к data атрибут в псевдоэлементе?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  background: #afafaf;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.progress:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: attr(data-progress) '%';
  /*width: 50%;*/
  background: #0faf0f;
  transition: width .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" data-progress="50"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без костылей, никак.
`attr(data-progress)` передает значение из `data-progress="50"` в виде строки.
`attr(...)` годится только для `content: ''`

Comment: Спасибо, понял, наверное до этого всегда со строкой имел дело, теперь буду знать. Придется со вложенным span использовать и делать через атрибут style по старинке)